# Rails init fails when using actionpack from vendor/gems directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.14

1) In my Gemgile I write

```
gem 'actionpack', '=2.3.14', :path => 'vendor/gems/rails/actionpack/actionpack-2.3.14'
gem 'rails', '=2.3.14'
```

2) bundle install

3) bundle show actionpack

```
/home/esk/tatventure/vendor/gems/rails/actionpack/actionpack-2.3.14
```

4) script/server

```
/home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:76:in `refresh!': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:45:in `each'
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:45:in `refresh!'
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:29:in `initialize'
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `new'
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path'
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:298:in `add_gem_load_paths'
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
from /home/esk/tatventure/config/environment.rb:9
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from /home/esk/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/commands/server.rb:84
from script/server:3:in `require'
from script/server:3
```

What could be done to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bit helpful:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6641-vendorgemsourceindexrefresh-fails-when-vendorgems-includes-cvs-directory